# Extracting clusters directly from correlation matrix?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a correlation matrix (how different variables are correlated with eachother); and am trying to find clusters based on groups of correlation. I am currently visualizing the dataset as follows to see how many possible groupings there are; and was wondering whether there was a way to directly extract out the clusters from the distance calculation instead of using k-means which will give me different results with each run?

For the below data, there are two clear clusters/possible groups, and I was wondering whether there is any program/tool/function that can extract it out?

Code:

```
library(factoextra)
distance <- get_dist(df)
fviz_dist(distance, gradient = list(low = "#00AFBB", mid = "white", high = "#FC4E07"))
```

Dataframe (row and column names correspond to unique IDs):

```
"","10039","10649","12095","12095x","12095xx","1250","12651","12757","1276","1278x"
"10039",0.255115618609175,-0.177854388857815,-0.0678361007484356,-0.352181285930436,-0.381869743064316,0.0997439892889507,-0.169349645042077,-0.00965202634702178,-0.0510234989805499,-0.0510234989805499
"10649",0.050959625003298,1,-0.0518039876671861,-0.179833539980186,0.050690373507738,0.128702514770023,-0.035435238826486,-0.0201628019873111,0.134771635570939,0.0356960459697166
"12095",-0.0216545036334337,-0.121466109785836,1,-0.1994809609399,-0.260343912678546,0.087392079332695,0.0123907872824176,0.087392079332695,0.087392079332695,-0.0216545036334337
"12095x",-0.098165021937254,-0.0458019488190383,0.00437032844659258,1,-0.113222380655106,-0.0402373870305558,0.0559033755079281,-0.0239049725192886,-0.0641124655537419,-0.0833206680201322
"12095xx",-0.166450101886438,0.0877515444667101,-0.163978399896905,-0.209807655480148,1,-0.15714120804553,-0.236776402855779,-0.210541064944441,-0.181807583843066,-0.19427423003104
"1250",1,0.187857639241878,0.220566284642567,-0.121083419077306,-0.137374140895616,1,0.34356843512983,1,1,1
"12651",0.252133611190047,0.119534413608904,0.24277152335447,0.0682069261602969,-0.130770022311008,0.435253016076324,1,0.630921537603276,0.411525000221144,0.371485268998199
"12757",0.124889049505779,-0.194934097542696,-0.0953559119912251,-0.276086004602751,-0.354148895078468,0.235644433149966,0.0645380123460424,0.38656429814172,0.0820770489758271,0.0820770489758271
"1276",0.45047612755622,0.0686398225015061,0.0952133592954676,-0.253496989469619,-0.270384179141728,1,0.19469614096637,0.45047612755622,1,1
"1278x",1,0.0367380740951311,0.0691680273310695,-0.254489814171706,-0.269208350534652,1,0.194504158280285,1,1,1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2976/60634

Comment: That "data.frame" is a comma-separated bunch of character values. You should instead post the output of `dput(dfrm)` instead.

Comment: What does a negative correlation mean as a distance? One method for working with correlation matrices is principal components analysis. The first component is the direction of maximum correlation in the matrix. The second is the next largest subject to the stipulation that the correlation between the two is 0. It does not divide the variables into distinct groups, but indicates how much of a particular variable is "explained" by each component. Alternatively you could square the correlations so that -1 and 1 are the same distance, 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means requires *coordinates*, not a distance matrix. So the k-means results are quite unreliable anyway.

Convert your correlation to a distance.

Then use hierarchical clustering, which accepts a distance matrix.